# Do Gmail's clients check 3rd party email in the cloud and do they scan non-Google email?

Tags: gmail, privacy, email-client

Google scans Gmail email to build an advertising profile in accordance with their privacy policy. The Gmail client can be used with non-Google email accounts. For example you can add an exchange email account in Gmail by inputting the mail server address and credentials.

- **Question1:**
  Does Google somehow still scan that email in the same way it scans Gmail email?
- **Question2:**
  Does the non-Google email checked via the Gmail client only pass between the 3rd party mail server and the phone (direct connection) or, e.g., does Google take the credentials you input in Gmail app and use them to check your email in the cloud and then forward the email to you via Google servers? (this is the most obvious way they would scan it I suppose?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a web application as defined on [help/on-topic].

Comment: Very helpful Ruben. Gmail is the very first example given at your link. "If your question generally covers [...] Gmail, [...] then you're in the right place".

Comment: Keep reading... "Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here"..." - Applications for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad"

Comment: Please also read the advice in the [gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/gmail/info) tag.

Comment: You have the option of answering the part of the question regarding gmail the web app. Other parts of the question are regarding the functionality of gmail the android app which may not happen within the locally running code of the app itself but instead may happen in the cloud, which would arguably and depending on the answer, make the entire question about a web application.

Comment: If it is that offensive to you to see a question that is only partially related to a web app rather than wholeheartedly and unequivocally focussed on a web app, you have the option of editing the question to focus on Q3 which would be a more constructive use of your time than telling me to go elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable compromise for the question to remain open.  If there is in fact a difference between the web client and the Android client, that aspect could be asked about at [Android.SE].  I'm not sure that anyone but Google is going to be able to answer this, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Google scans Gmail email to build an advertising profile in accordance with their privacy policy.

As there are several variants of Gmail, it's worth to say that users of G Suite for Education accounts don't see advertisements. Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/139019?hl=en

> The Gmail client can be used with non-Google email accounts. For example you can add an exchange email account in Gmail by inputting the mail server address and credentials.
>   Question1: Does Google somehow still scan that email in the same way it scans Gmail email?

The Gmail web client requires that the messages are on the Gmail servers, so  its very likely that they are scanned as any other message.